# Having a persistent IRC client

Tags: shell, nohup, irc, irssi

I would like to have an IRC client (running on a server that I have SSH access to) be persistent on the server without disconnecting from the rooms and servers I joined. In other words, I want to be able to SSH into a server, check messages on the IRC client, disconnect from the SSH server, without ever leaving the chatrooms.

How can I achieve that? I'm using `irssi` and thought about somehow `nohup`'ing it, but I can't see how that would work.

Comment: Run it in a multiplexer (like `tmux`).

Comment: would that keep it running on the background? I thought it would just freeze-state it.

Comment: It keeps it running; if you detach, it sets you as away.